# Pygame - put updating mouse coords on the screen

Tags: text, pygame, coordinates, mouse

Can anyone help me figure out how to put constantly updating ouse coords in the upper right corner of the screen? I think it would be a big help to have it there just for dev purposes, but I cant figure it out. Here is my code so far:

```
'''
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Sat Oct 17 20:26:57 2020

@author: wohlsr
"""

import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from sys import exit

background_image_filename = ('menu-start.jpg')
mouse_image_filename = ('mouse-pointer.png')
icon = pygame.image.load('go-stop-icon.png')

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1024, 768), 0, 32)
pygame.display.set_caption("Gostop")
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)
background = pygame.image.load(background_image_filename).convert()
mouse_cursor = pygame.image.load(mouse_image_filename).convert_alpha()



while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            exit()
            
    pygame.mouse.set_visible(0)
    screen.blit(background, (0,0))
    x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    x-= mouse_cursor.get_width() / 2
    y-= mouse_cursor.get_height() / 2
    screen.blit(mouse_cursor, (x, y))

    

    pygame.display.update()
'''
```

[Visual of what I have so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWuHa.jpg)

Comment: Which part of the code is not working?  I can't see anything that tries to draw the mouse co-ordinates in the top-right corner.

Comment: @Kingsley: Because I took it out. I can display a string of text easily. But if I try to use x, y that I have already defined, it freaks out over x and y being floats. (I have no idea why they are floats anyway - you cant utilize fractions of pixels...)

Answer (score 1):

This code puts the mouse position in the top right corner of the screen.

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from sys import exit

background_image_filename = ('menu-start.jpg')
mouse_image_filename = ('mouse-pointer.png')
icon = pygame.image.load('go-stop-icon.png')

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1024, 768), 0, 32)
pygame.display.set_caption("Gostop")
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)
background = pygame.image.load(background_image_filename).convert()
mouse_cursor = pygame.image.load(mouse_image_filename).convert_alpha()

font=pygame.font.SysFont('arial',20,True,False)  # font for mouse position
def showcoords(screen,x,y):
    q1Text= font.render("{}  {}".format(int(x),int(y)).center(20),1,(0,0,0))  # surface with coord text
    bg = q1Text.copy()  # copy surface for background
    bg.fill((0,100,100))  # background
    textRect = q1Text.get_rect()   
    textRect.topright = ((1024,0))  # put in top\right corner
    screen.blit(bg,textRect)  # draw background
    screen.blit(q1Text,textRect)  # draw coords



while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            exit()
            
    pygame.mouse.set_visible(0)
    screen.blit(background, (0,0))
    x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    x-= mouse_cursor.get_width() / 2
    y-= mouse_cursor.get_height() / 2
    screen.blit(mouse_cursor, (x, y))

    showcoords(screen,x,y)  # show mouse coords

    pygame.display.update()
```

If you want to use the global x,y values without passing parameters, make these changes:

```
def showcoords(screen):
    global x,y  # use existing x,y values
    .......

showcoords(screen)  # show mouse coords
```

Output

[image: Mouse]

Comment: Thanks Mike67! I was trying to use x and y already proclaimed through the mouse movement section for the custom cursor and it wasn't working out because it was a float and I couldn't print text as float. I will tackle this after work today.

Comment: The mouse coordinates are always integers, If you display as a float it will just end with zeros.

Comment: Yes, put looking at my code, do you see floats happening? if I just do "print (x,y)" to put it to terminal, it does print 123.0. Not sure why. Forgive my ignorance, I am just learning.

Comment: Using a single slash for division always returns a float: `mouse_cursor.get_width() / 2`. For int, use a double slash: `mouse_cursor.get_width() // 2`